# Why does Python's math.factorial not play nice with threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, blocking, factorial, gil

Why does math.factorial act so weird in a thread?

Here is an example, it creates three threads:

- thread that just sleeps for a while
- thread that increments an int for a while
- thread that does math.factorial on a large number.

It calls `start` on the threads, then `join` with a timeout

The sleep and spin threads work as expected and return from `start` right away, and then sit in the `join` for the timeout.

The factorial thread on the other hand does not return from `start` until it runs to the end!

```py
import sys
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep, time
from math import factorial

# Helper class that stores a start time to compare to
class timed_thread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, time_start):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.time_start = time_start

# Thread that just executes sleep()
class sleep_thread(timed_thread):
    def run(self):
        sleep(15)
        print "st DONE:\t%f" % (time() - time_start)

# Thread that increments a number for a while       
class spin_thread(timed_thread):
    def run(self):
        x = 1
        while x < 120000000:
            x += 1
        print "sp DONE:\t%f" % (time() - time_start)

# Thread that calls math.factorial with a large number
class factorial_thread(timed_thread):
    def run(self):
        factorial(50000)
        print "ft DONE:\t%f" % (time() - time_start)

# the tests

print
print "sleep_thread test"
time_start = time()

st = sleep_thread(time_start)
st.start()
print "st.start:\t%f" % (time() - time_start)
st.join(2)
print "st.join:\t%f" % (time() - time_start)
print "sleep alive:\t%r" % st.isAlive()


print
print "spin_thread test"
time_start = time()

sp = spin_thread(time_start)
sp.start()
print "sp.start:\t%f" % (time() - time_start)
sp.join(2)
print "sp.join:\t%f" % (time() - time_start)
print "sp alive:\t%r" % sp.isAlive()

print
print "factorial_thread test"
time_start = time()

ft = factorial_thread(time_start)
ft.start()
print "ft.start:\t%f" % (time() - time_start)
ft.join(2)
print "ft.join:\t%f" % (time() - time_start)
print "ft alive:\t%r" % ft.isAlive()
```

And here is the output on Python 2.6.5 on CentOS x64:

```
sleep_thread test
st.start:       0.000675
st.join:        2.006963
sleep alive:    True

spin_thread test
sp.start:       0.000595
sp.join:        2.010066
sp alive:       True

factorial_thread test
ft DONE:        4.475453
ft.start:       4.475589
ft.join:        4.475615
ft alive:       False
st DONE:        10.994519
sp DONE:        12.054668
```

I've tried this on python 2.6.5 on CentOS x64, 2.7.2 on Windows x86 and the factorial thread does not return from start on either of them until the thread is done executing.

I've also tried this with PyPy 1.8.0 on Windows x86, and there result is slightly different. The start *does* return immediately, but then the join doesn't time out!

```
sleep_thread test
st.start:       0.001000
st.join:        2.001000
sleep alive:    True

spin_thread test
sp.start:       0.000000
sp DONE:        0.197000
sp.join:        0.236000
sp alive:       False

factorial_thread test
ft.start:       0.032000
ft DONE:        9.011000
ft.join:        9.012000
ft alive:       False
st DONE:        12.763000
```

Tried IronPython 2.7.1 too, it produces the expected result.

```
sleep_thread test
st.start:       0.023003
st.join:        2.028122
sleep alive:    True

spin_thread test
sp.start:       0.003014
sp.join:        2.003128
sp alive:       True

factorial_thread test
ft.start:       0.002991
ft.join:        2.004105
ft alive:       True
ft DONE:        5.199295
sp DONE:        5.734322
st DONE:        10.998619
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Threads often only allow different things to be interleaved in Python, not different things to happen at the same time, because of the [Global Interpreter Lock](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock).

If you look at the Python bytecode:

```
from math import factorial

def fac_test(x):
    factorial(x)

import dis
dis.dis(fac_test)
```

you get:

```
  4           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (factorial)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              9 POP_TOP             
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             13 RETURN_VALUE
```

As you can see, the call to `math.factorial` is a single operation at the Python bytecode level (`6 CALL_FUNCTION`) -- it's implemented in C. `factorial` doesn't release the GIL because of the type of work it does (see the comments on my answer), so Python doesn't switch to other threads while it's running, and you get the result you've observed.

Comment: "Because of that, Python doesn't switch to other threads while it's running ..." No, that's not why.

Comment: The problem isn't that the functioncall is a single bytecode -- lots of things that allow other threads to execute happen in a single bytecode. The problem is that the math.factorial function doesn't release the global interpreter lock because all the work it does touches PyObjects, which means it has to have the GIL to do anything. It could conceivably release-and-reacquire the GIL, although it doesn't.

Comment: @ThomasWouters I've slightly modified my answer; I oversimplified.

Comment: Wow, that's interesting. What about the slightly better working PyPy? Their factorial implementation is all python https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/src/2346207d9946/pypy/module/math/app_math.py, which start()s fine, but prevents join from timing out.

Comment: @W1N9Zr0 You should ask that as a separate question. I don't know why that would happen -- could it just be taking a really long time? Is it just the factorial that isn't joining? Try a smaller number.

Comment: PyPy's implementation is RPython, not Python, it does not run bytecodes nor release the GIL in this code. I suppose it simply runs faster or the GIL is slightly smarter, but nothing really that different.

Answer (score 2):

Python has a Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) which makes requires CPU-bound threads to take turns instead of running concurrently. Since the factorial function is written in C and does not release the GIL, even setting `sys.setswitchinterval` isn't enough to let threads cooperate.

The `multiprocessing` module provides Process objects, which are like threads but work in separate address spaces. For CPU-bound tasks, you should strongly consider using the `multiprocessing` module.